# The multi-part identifier could not be bound in SQL Server and it confused

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join, window-functions

I have this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
    stu.sno, sname, cname
FROM
    sc scc,
    (SELECT AVG(sc.grade) AS avg_grade 
     FROM sc 
     GROUP BY sc.cno) AS avg_grades
INNER JOIN 
    course c ON c.cno = scc.cno
INNER JOIN 
    s stu ON stu.sno = scc.sno;
```

And there is an error that the multi-part identifier `scc.cno` could not be bound. I'm confused - could someone help me?

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explixit join syntax

Comment: You probably intended the `SELECT AVG(...)` subquery to be part of the `SELECT`, not the `FROM`.

Comment: Is there really a table named `s`? Or should that be the alias? And no where do you use the average in top level query.

Comment: The sc represents for the student-course-selection, and I want to select the stu name whose grade (stored in table sc) in one or more course is lower than the average grade of that course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix implicit and explicit joins! Matter of fact, don't use implicit joins: this is archaic syntax, that should not appear in new code.

The comma in the `FROM` clause should (probably) be a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT stu.sno, sname, cname
FROM sc scc
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(sc.grade) AS avg_grade FROM sc GROUP BY sc.cno) AS avg_grades
INNER JOIN course c on c.cno = scc.cno
INNER JOIN s stu on stu.sno = scc.sno;
```

Note that, for this subquery to be useful, you would probably need to `select` column `avg_grade`. I would also recommend prefixing each column with the table it belongs to, to remove any possible ambiguity.

Finally: you (probably) can use window functions instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT stu.sno, sname, cname, scc.
FROM (SELECT *, AVG(grade) OVER() avg_grade FROM sc) scc
INNER JOIN course c on c.cno = scc.cno
INNER JOIN s stu on stu.sno = scc.sno;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a one-to-many join of *students* and *courses* and joined table of student courses (i.e., `sc`), consider a simplified aggregation on joined tables. Be sure to always qualify columns with alias if query contains more than on table:

```sql
SELECT 
    s.sno AS student_number
    , s.sname AS student_name
    , c.cname AS course_name
    , AVG(sc.grade) AS avg_grade
FROM
    sc
INNER JOIN 
    course c ON c.cno = sc.cno
INNER JOIN 
    stu s ON s.sno = sc.sno
GROUP BY
    s.sno
    , s.sname
    , c.cname
```